# Checking if an item has been modified within 24 hours

Tags: vb.net

I have code that generates a verification code. I need to check to see if that code has been generated within 24 hours. If it has I need it to resend the same code. If it is over 24 hours I need it to send another code. All of this works except checking if the code is generated within 24 hours or if it is after. I can explain the code if need be.

```
    'This gets the current date
    Dim CurrentDate As Date
    CurrentDate = Today

    'This gets the randomly generated verification code
    For i As Integer = 1 To cnt
        Dim idx As Integer = r.Next(0, s.Length)
        sb.Append(s.Substring(idx, 1))

    'This generates another if the Resend Verification code button is clicked
    Next

    oWebUserGE.SetValue("VerificationCode__pbi", sb.ToString()) 
    oWebUserGE.Save()

    oResultCode.Value = "SUCCESS"
    Catch ex As System.Exception
    oResultCode.Value = "FAILED"
    End Try
```

Comment: Store it in a database along with the creation date?

Comment: I will try to do that. I'm trying not to have the code handed to me. If I didn't want to store it in a database and just have it stored and ran in that code how could I do it?

Comment: If you can't save it somewhere, maybe weave a timestamp into your verification code generating logic?

Comment: Best solution would be storing it in the database imo.  Simplest solution for what you want (imo) would probably be to append the creation time to the end of the string builder and then check it. Use a separator, then split on the separator, parse to date, and check it vs now.

Comment: Thank you all for the helpful comments. @Aaron would you be able to link me more information on how to do what you suggested?

Comment: I'll give you an example. I'm out of the office for the next few mins but if nobody else gets it before I get back upstairs I'll write something quick up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is sort of how I would do it if I didn't have a database. Please note that there are no validation checks - I leave that to you.

```
Imports System.Text

Public Class Form1
Public Sub New()
    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()
    DoWork()
    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
End Sub

Private Sub DoWork()
    'Test Case. Receiving a code > 24 hours old.
    Console.WriteLine("Test 1 Start - Old Code")
    Dim sOldVerificationCode As String = GenerateVerificationCode(False)
    Dim bUpdate As Boolean = CheckCode(sOldVerificationCode)
    If bUpdate Then
        Dim sNew As String = GenerateVerificationCode(True)
        Console.WriteLine("Generating New Code. Old Code Expired: " + sNew + Environment.NewLine + "Test Passed")
    Else
        Console.WriteLine("Test Failed.")
    End If
    Console.WriteLine("Test 1 Finished - Old Code" + Environment.NewLine)
    Console.WriteLine("Test 2 Start - New Code")
    'Test Case. Receiving a code < 24 hours old.
    Dim sNewVerificationCode As String = GenerateVerificationCode(True)
    bUpdate = CheckCode(sNewVerificationCode)
    If bUpdate Then
        Console.WriteLine("Test Failed.")
    Else
        Console.WriteLine("Code Is Good. No New Code Generated." + Environment.NewLine + "Test Passed")
    End If
    Console.WriteLine("Test 2 Finished - New Code")
End Sub

Private Function CheckCode(ByVal sOldVerificationCode As String) As Boolean
    Dim sVerCodeRaw As String = System.Net.WebUtility.UrlDecode(sOldVerificationCode) 'Url Decode, back to Base64 string.
    Dim stringBytes As Byte() = Convert.FromBase64String(sVerCodeRaw) 'Get Base64 bytes.
    Dim sVerCode As String = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stringBytes) 'Get Raw String
    Dim sCode As String = sVerCode.Split("|")(0) 'Code part
    Dim sDate As String = sVerCode.Split("|")(1) 'Date part
    Dim dtOldCode As DateTime = DateTime.Parse(sDate).ToLocalTime()
    Return DateDiff(DateInterval.Day, dtOldCode, DateTime.Now) > 0
End Function

Private Function GenerateVerificationCode(ByVal bNew As Boolean) As String 'Dual purpose so we don't need 2 functions for nearly identical tasks.
    Dim CurrentDate As DateTime = IIf(bNew, DateTime.Now, DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -2, DateTime.Now))
    Dim sb As New StringBuilder()
    sb.Append(Guid.NewGuid.ToString().Replace("-", "")) 'Unique instead of random. Random is not unique.
    sb.Append("|" + CurrentDate.ToUniversalTime().ToString()) 'Using UTC in case multiple servers in different timezones.
    Dim stringBytes As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sb.ToString()) 'Byte array for use in converting to Base64.
    Dim verCodeRaw As String = Convert.ToBase64String(stringBytes) 'now a base64 encoded string. This will make it look like gibberish in the 
    Dim urlVerification As String = System.Net.WebUtility.UrlEncode(verCodeRaw) 'Now URL Safe. Assuming it'll be a Get parameter.
    Return urlVerification
End Function
End Class
```

This outputs:

```
Test 1 Start - Old Code
Old Code Expired. Generating New Code: Y2Q1Nzg0M2VjNTVlNDU3Njk1MDU4OTBiMmI1NTEzN2F8Mi8yMy8yMDE4IDc6NTc6NDYgUE0%3D
Test Passed
Test 1 Finished - Old Code

Test 2 Start - New Code
Code Is Good. No New Code Generated.
Test Passed
Test 2 Finished - New Code
```

You can insert breakpoints to check intermediate values.

I have converted it to a Base64 string, and then URL Encoded it. *THIS IS NOT SECURE* but it does look better if attached to a link as a GET.

I have also used a GUID instead of your random number generator. This guarantees a *unique* value - your random number generation is not guaranteed to be unique.

Comment: Thank you for the information. This has helped me tremendously!